# Updateing a table using Checkbox in datagridview

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, checkbox

I have a datagridview with a checkbox column at the beginning, what i want to happen is that when I press the Ok button it will update the Requested row in my EquipmentDetail table with the corresponding checked chekcboxes.

The problem is that when I check even only one checkbox ... All of the  rows are updated into true even if its not checked in the datagridview ...

```
 For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        req = row.Cells(Column1.Name).Value
        If row.Cells("Column1").Value = True Then
            Dim sql2 As String = "UPDATE EquipmentDetail SET Requested = '" & req & "'"
            cmd2.Connection = connection
            cmd2.CommandText = sql2
            cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End If
    Next
    connection.Close()
End Sub
```

help me please ... thanks ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your update statement you are updating all records in the EquipmentDetail table, you should have a "WHERE" clause in the UPDATE statement.

Dim sql2 As String = "UPDATE EquipmentDetail SET Requested = '" & req & "'" & "WHERE ID=" & ID(*the id of the Row in the EquipmentDetail table*)

Hope this helps!